# What is the purpose of using OR operation on a varible with empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean-operations

I found that implementation on a google analytics script in one of my project pages.

I was wondering what is the purpose of first line :  "myArray || [] "" ?

Why to use OR operation on an array with another empty array?

```js
  var myArray = myArray || [];
  myArray.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-39103830-1']);
  myArray.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: Or on any other kind of object,does not have to be array. Why to OR it with another empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "or" operation assigns an empty array to `myArray` if it does not exist. The code above is functionally equivalent to:

```
if(myArray == null || myArray==undefined)
    myArray = [];
myArray.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-39103830-1']);
myArray.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: FYI its actually more like `if(myArray == null || myArray == undefined || myArray == 0) // or any other falsey value`

Comment: Yeah sure. I modified a little bit the answer.

Comment: This example helped me to get main idea,thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you observe the below snippet, it checks for falsy values such as `undefined` `null`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, `""` and `NaN` (but also empty arrays `[]`) it will assign the right if so.

```js
var arr; // undefined
var arr = arr || [];
console.log(arr) // Output: []

var arr = null; // null
var arr = arr || [];
console.log(arr) // Output: []

var arr = ""; // empty string
var arr = arr || [];
console.log(arr) // Output: []

var arr = "Mr.7"; // string
var arr = arr || [];
console.log(arr) // Output: Mr.7
```